# Excel if function please guide

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i want to change the value of cell using if function  like =**if(A1=A2,A3=4,"")** if A1 is equal to A2 then change the value of A4 and i don't want to write this formula in A4

Comment: Excel formulas do not change the value of another cell. They are intended to return a value to the cell in which they reside.

Comment: Why must you use an “if function” and why do you not “write this formula in A4”?

Comment: so please tell me the VBA code for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Excel formulas can only effect the cell that they are in, unfortunately.  You can do this with Visual Basic, but it's not a simple fix.

Comment: This is a comment on the original question; not an answer.

Comment: We said basically the same thing with a different sentence structure, how is this not an answer (sorry, am new).

Comment: @AdamSimmons - While *you cannot get there from here* does actually answer the question it would best be left as a comment to the question as it is unlikely to provide assistance to any future viewer of this question. The OP has shown no original effort beyond demanding that someone *'tell me the VB code for this'* and sometimes it is best to let questions like this die on the vine. It is harder for that to happen when an answer has been posted. Once you gain some rep you will be able to respond to any post or question with a comment.

Comment: i new here i relay don't no how to question this is my first ever question on this website

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
With ActiveSheet
If ( .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A2").Value ) Then
  .Range("A4") = <your value>
EndIf
```